# How to get rid off this error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in fun.php on line 608?

Tags: php, domdocument, fatal-error

I'm having following function code. In this function I'm passing some HTML data and cleaning up this HTML data. But I'm getting the error as follows:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in fun.php on line 608
```

I got this error during debugging my code. For debugging purpose I wrote following two lines:

```
        $test = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
        echo  $test; die;/*This is Line No. 608 where error is coming*/
```

I'm not understanding how to resolve this error. I'm a newbie to the concept of **The DOMDocument class** in PHP, so I'm totally confused what's the error coming and how to resolve it. Can anyone please help me in this regard? For your reference I'm giving below the function definition and the argument which I'm passing to the function.

```
function clear_question_data($html) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $test = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
        echo  $test; die;/*This is Line No. 608 where error is coming*/
        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
        {   echo "In a loop"; die;
            $image->removeAttribute('alt');
            $image->removeAttribute('xmlns');
            $image->removeAttribute('title');
        }
        echo "Out of the loop"; die;

            $txt=$dom->saveHTML();

            $dom->loadHTML($txt);

            foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
            {
                $srcval=$image->getAttribute('src');

                $srcval = htmlspecialchars_decode($srcval);

                $srcval = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $srcval);  

                if(strpos($srcval,"%5C%22")==0)
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("%5C%22", "", $srcval);
                    $srcval = str_replace(".png%5C%22", ".png", $srcval);
                }
                if(strpos($srcval,"../../..")==0)
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("../../..", "", $srcval);
                }
                if(strpos($srcval,"../..")==0)
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("../..", "", $srcval);
                }
                if(strpos($srcval,"/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins")==0) 
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("/ckeditor_3.6.1//", EPN_SITE_URL."ckeditor_3.6.1/", $srcval);
                }


                  $srcval = str_replace(".png/\"", ".png", $srcval);
                  $srcval = str_replace("�", "-", $srcval);

                $image->setAttribute('src',$srcval);
            }   
            $final_data=$dom->saveHTML();

            return $final_data;
    }
```

The argument `$html` which I'm passing to the function is as follows:

```
$html=Glucose when hetaed with CH&lt;sub&gt;3&lt;/sub&gt;OH in presence of dry HCl gas gives&lt;img align=&quot;middle&quot; alt=&quot;�math xmlns=�http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML���mi��#945;�/mi��/math�&quot; class=&quot;Wirisformula&quot; src=&quot;/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=dedbf6a559a928eeeaee82c4b1bf40d3.png&quot; title=&quot;Double click to edit&quot;&gt; and &lt;img align=&quot;middle&quot; alt=&quot;�math xmlns=�http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML���mi��#946;�/mi��/math�&quot; class=&quot;Wirisformula&quot; src=&quot;/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=2c5cf4a4494a03be06d6c32308a225ba.png&quot; title=&quot;Double click to edit&quot;&gt;-methyl glycosides because it contains.&lt;br&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo` is trying to convert `$test` into a string because [`echo` only handles strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (look at the argument variable type).

Try using `var_dump($test);` or even `die(var_dump($test));` to display the value of `$test`;

Comment: :I tried with die(var_dump($test)); It given me the output  object(DOMNodeList)#12 (0) {
}
So what should I do now. My real issue is I'm not able to get inside the foreach loop. Once I able to get inside foreach then everything will work fine for me. Can you help me in correcting my error if any.

Comment: The output `object(DOMNodeList)#12 (0) { }` means that your call `$dom->getElementsByTagName('img');` didn't grab anything. Since the object is empty, there's nothing to iterate for the loop. I wish I could provide more information, but I don't know anything about DOMNodeList; only troubleshooting PHP.

Answer (score 0):

OBVIOUSLY.

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

$test is object of DOMNodeList.

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domnodelist.php

You only have property `length` and method `item($i)` in addition to `Traversable` interface.